# aggregate by value and count, distinct array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Let's say i have this list of tuples

```
[
('r', 'p', ['A', 'B']),
('r', 'f', ['A']),
('r', 'e', ['A']),
('r', 'p', ['A']),
('r', 'f', ['B']),
('r', 'p', ['B']),
('r', 'e', ['B']),
('r', 'c', ['A'])
]
```

Need to return a list of tuples that aggregated (group by) by the second value in the tuple, count the number of the aggregation.
for the third value, which is an array, need to distinct and aggregate it.

So for the example above, the result will be:

```
[
('r', 'p', ['A', 'B'], 4),
('r', 'f', ['A', 'B'], 2),
('r', 'e', ['A', 'B'], 2),
('r', 'c', ['A'], 1)
]
```

In the result, the first value is a const, the second is unique (it was grouped by) the third is distinct grouped array, and the forth is the count of values of the array if we grouped them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well:

```py
data = [
    ("r", "p", ["A", "B"]),
    ("r", "f", ["A"]),
    ("r", "e", ["A"]),
    ("r", "p", ["A"]),
    ("r", "f", ["B"]),
    ("r", "p", ["B"]),
    ("r", "e", ["B"]),
    ("r", "c", ["A"]),
]

out = {}
for a, b, c in data:
    out.setdefault((a, b), []).append(c)

out = [
    (a, b, list(set(v for l in c for v in l)), sum(map(len, c)))
    for (a, b), c in out.items()
]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ("r", "p", ["B", "A"], 4),
    ("r", "f", ["B", "A"], 2),
    ("r", "e", ["B", "A"], 2),
    ("r", "c", ["A"], 1),
]
```

Comment: can u plz explain how this lines works: 
(a, b, list(set(v for l in c for v in l)), sum(map(len, c)))
for (a, b), c in out.items()
?

Comment: @lolo The `set(v for l in c for v in l)` will remove all duplicates from `[["A", "B"], ["A"], ["B"]]`, so it becomes `{"A", "B"}`. with `list()` we convert this set to a list. `sum(map(len, c))` will count the total number of elements in this list-of-lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
('r', 'p', ['A', 'B']),
('r', 'f', ['A']),
('r', 'e', ['A']),
('r', 'p', ['A']),
('r', 'f', ['B']),
('r', 'p', ['B']),
('r', 'e', ['B']),
('r', 'c', ['A'])
], columns=['first','second','arr'])

pd.merge(df.explode('arr').groupby(['first','second']).agg(set).reset_index(),
         df[['first','second']].value_counts().reset_index(),
         on=['first','second']).values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[
    ['r', 'c', {'A'}, 1],
    ['r', 'e', {'B', 'A'}, 2],
    ['r', 'f', {'B', 'A'}, 2],
    ['r', 'p', {'B', 'A'}, 3]
]
```

To address your edit you could do this:

```
(
  df.explode('arr')
    .value_counts()
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(['first','second'])
    .agg({'arr':set, 0:sum})
    .reset_index()
    .values
    .tolist()
)
```

Output

```
[
   ['r', 'c', {'A'}, 1],
   ['r', 'e', {'B', 'A'}, 2],
   ['r', 'f', {'B', 'A'}, 2],
   ['r', 'p', {'B', 'A'}, 4]
]
```

Comment: i edit the question, it should be ('r', 'p', ['A', 'B'], 4) not ('r', 'p', ['A', 'B'], 3), the count is the number of values of the array, if it's concatenate. if we group by p we will get for the array: ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'] so it's 4. and need to distinct the array, so the result for this row will be:  ('r', 'p', ['A', 'B'], 4)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt using `itertools`.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
('r', 'p', ['A', 'B']),
('r', 'f', ['A']),
('r', 'e', ['A']),
('r', 'p', ['A']),
('r', 'f', ['B']),
('r', 'p', ['B']),
('r', 'e', ['B']),
('r', 'c', ['A'])
]

# groupby needs sorted data
data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
result = []
for key,group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    # Make the AB list. Ex: s = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
    s = [item for x in group for item in x[2]]
    # Put it all together. Ex: ('r', 'p', ['A', 'B'], 4)
    result.append(tuple(list(key) + [list(set(s))] + [len(s)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

[convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) supports custom aggregations (I must confess, I'm the author), so here's the code:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

data = [
    ("r", "p", ["A", "B"]),
    ("r", "f", ["A"]),
    ("r", "e", ["A"]),
    ("r", "p", ["A"]),
    ("r", "f", ["B"]),
    ("r", "p", ["B"]),
    ("r", "e", ["B"]),
    ("r", "c", ["A"]),
]

converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(1))
    .aggregate(
        (
            c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item(0)),
            c.item(1),
            c.reduce(
                lambda x, y: x.union(y),
                c.item(2).as_type(set),
                initial=set,
                default=set,
            ).as_type(list),
            c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item(2).len()),
        )
    )
    .gen_converter()  # generates ad-hoc python function; reuse if needed
)
```

The output is:

```
In [47]: converter(data)
Out[47]:
[('r', 'p', ['B', 'A'], 4),
 ('r', 'f', ['B', 'A'], 2),
 ('r', 'e', ['B', 'A'], 2),
 ('r', 'c', ['A'], 1)]
```